# Connecting client to server with BufferedReader and DataOutputStream using java not working, no error being displayed either

Tags: java, sockets

I'd like to be able to connect the client file to the server file so that I can retrieve data from the server and display it to the user from the client file. Currently the data is being retrieved from the data files without any problems but it's just the connection between the server and the client which is causing some trouble.

I run the server file first and then run the client file, both run fine and are both using the same port on localhost, but there's no connection between the two.

Client:

```
package com.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectClient {

static boolean run = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8901);

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while(run) {

            System.out.println("Select which data you would like to view:");
            System.out.println("1: Light Data");
            System.out.println("2: Temperature Data");
            System.out.println("3: Humidity Data");
            System.out.println("4: Exit");
            System.out.print("Enter option: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option = sc.nextInt();

            if(option > 0 && option < 4) {
                outToServer.writeBytes(option + "");                    
                displayMsg("FROM SERVER: " + inFromServer.readLine());
                run = true;
            } else if(option == 4) {
                displayMsg("Goodbye");
                run = false;
            } 
            else {
                displayMsg("Invalid Option");
                run = true;
            }
        }

        clientSocket.close();        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void displayMsg(String msg) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println("");
}

}
```

Server:

```
package com.server;

import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;

public class ProjectServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8901);
        int clientOption;

        while(true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = listener.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            clientOption = Integer.parseInt(inFromClient.readLine());

            System.out.println("Received: " + clientOption);

            String dataResults = getDataFromFiles(clientOption);
            outToClient.writeBytes(dataResults);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getDataFromFiles(int option) {
    String result = "";

    switch(option) {
        case 1:
            result = getData("light.dat");
        break;

        case 2:
            result = getData("temperature.dat");
        break;

        case 3:
            result = getData("humidity.dat");
        break;            
    }

    return result;
}

private static String getData(String fileName) {
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {            
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/ryan/Desktop/" + fileName));
        String currentLine;

        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            result += currentLine + "\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

There's no error being displayed either when I try to return the data to the client. I'm just wondering if there's something missing. I'd really appreciate any and all help I get with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a active Connection.
Your have to make a little change to your code.
Add to Client:

```
outToServer.writeByte('\n');
```

Direct after:

```
outToServer.writeBytes(option + "");
```

You have to add the new line, because your server calls .readLine(), but this method reads data until a '\n' is noticed.
[Java Doc Class BufferedReader - readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())
So your you have a active connection and you are sending your data but your Server doesn't react because it is waiting for the '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it like that. You need to write new line character.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectClient {

    static boolean run = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 8901);


            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            Scanner serverScanner = new Scanner(inFromServer);


            while(run) {

                System.out.println("Select which data you would like to view:");
                System.out.println("1: Light Data");
                System.out.println("2: Temperature Data");
                System.out.println("3: Humidity Data");
                System.out.println("4: Exit");
                System.out.print("Enter option: ");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int option = sc.nextInt();

                if(option > 0 && option < 4) {
                    System.out.println("to server " + option);
                    out.writeBytes(option + "\n");
                    displayMsg("FROM SERVER: " + serverScanner.next());
                    run = true;
                } else if(option == 4) {
                    displayMsg("Goodbye");
                    run = false;
                }
                else {
                    displayMsg("Invalid Option");
                    run = true;
                }
            }

            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void displayMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println("");
    }

}



import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8901);
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);

            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +  serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                    Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

                    System.out.println("Just connected to "  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(server.getInputStream());

                    String op = sc.next();


                    System.out.println(op);

                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeUTF(getDataFromFiles(Integer.parseInt(op)));
                    out.flush();
                    server.close();
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                    System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private static String getDataFromFiles(int option) {
        String result = "";

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                result = "light.dat";
                break;

            case 2:
                result = "temperature.dat";
                break;

            case 3:
                result = "humidity.dat";
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String getData(String fileName) {
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/ryan/Desktop/" + fileName));
            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result += currentLine + "\n";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```